# Equivariant line bundles over toric variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $X$ be a projective $n$-dimensional toric variety acted by an algebraic torus $T\simeq \mathbb{C}^{\ast n}$. It is well known that  any piecewise linear (and integer in some sense)  function on the fan corresponding to $X$ defines a $T$-equivariant bundle $L$ over $X$. It is ample if and only if the function is strictly convex on the fan.

I want to use more the fact that  everything is $T$-equivariant. (The following construction is used in the definition of $T$-equivariant cohomology of $X$ and $T$-equivariant Chern classes of $L$.)

Since the bundle $L$ is $T$-equivariant it defines a line bundle
$\mathcal{L}_N:=L\times_{(\mathbb{C}^{\ast})^n}(\mathbb{C}^N\backslash\{0\})^n$ for any $N$ which is a bundle over $\mathcal{X}_N:=X\times_{\mathbb{C}^{\ast n}}(\mathbb{C}^N\backslash\{0\})^n$. The latter space is a compact algebraic variety naturally fibered over $(\mathbb{CP}^{N-1})^n$ with fiber $X$.

**Under what conditions on the piecewise linear function, the line bundle $\mathcal{L}_N$ over $\mathcal{X}_N$ is ample   ?**

A reference will be helpful.